# Does removing the bonus action requirement of two weapon fighting make it unbalanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, house-rules, two-weapon-fighting, action-economy

I've been toying with various approaches to making Two-Weapon Fighting interact better with other class features that use a bonus action. I am considering removing the bonus action requirement of Two-Weapon Fighting, either outright or as an addition to the Dual Wielder Feat. The additional attack is still limited to once per turn.

Does experience with this house rule reveal exploits or that it makes things unbalanced?

Comment: Note: you speak in comments of a Barbarian under Frenzy not being able to optimally use TWF which made me thing => do you want to change the rules, or the style? D&D is not upheld by the WYSIWYG rule (What You See Is What You Get) that some figurine tabletop games are, so you can perfectly have a Barbarian character wielding two hand-axes for style points, but then use the rules & damage of a great axe. Just consider that he always strike with both hand-axe at the same time.

Comment: Mrm, maybe that could be more workable. There's always fluff, after all. The thing is, the game has rules for two-weapon fighting, and it just feels weird not to use them--- but then they don't mesh well with certain martial archetypes.

Comment: Isn't this question kind of opinion based? I am not sure how the guidelines are on what you can do and can't, but the answers that can be given may be less factual & more off opinions?

Answer (score 35):

### Unequivocally: Yes

The single biggest limitation on PCs (or any creature) is the restriction imposed by the action economy, specifically:

- one move
- one action
- *potentially* [one interaction (free)](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=73)
- *potentially* one bonus action
- *potentially* one reaction

#### Mess with this at your peril

In a combat, the side that can consistently make the better choices for the use of these limited opportunities to act will, all else being equal, win.

There *should* be pressure on a PC to struggle with if the Attack, Disengage, or Hide action is *the* best choice right now. Similarly, PCs should always be looking for ways to trigger a bonus action rather than not **and** making decisions about *which* bonus action is optimal.

With particular reference to two weapon fighting, there is an inherent trade off between making another attack versus using a more damaging weapon or getting extra protection from a shield: this doesn't change under your proposal. Notwithstanding, two weapon fighting is powerful - it doubles the potential damage output of low level martial characters and while it's utility lessens for characters that get extra attacks it is still a solid bonus action choice. Which is really the point: it should remain a choice - not something with no cost.

However, to consider just one potential abuse of your system: I will play a rogue who uses daggers (light finesse melee weapons that can be used for two-weapon fighting and trigger sneak attack). At second level I get cunning action - if I use the bonus action to hide I will get advantage on my first attack and trigger my sneak attack damage. Under the published rules I have to make a choice: hide and make one attack with advantage and sneak attack damage *or* make two attacks. Under your proposal I will always hide and make my first attack with advantage and sneak attack and get my second attack as well. A difficult choice becomes a no brainer and that is *not* a good thing.

Comment: Is it really that much of a problem? If anything, I'm more worried about the monk using TWF and Martial Arts/Flurry of Blows. I'm mostly considering this because there seems to be a lot of features, like the Berserker Barbarian's Frenzy, where the character is hampered if they use TWF.

Comment: Barbarian's Frenzy (and many other features) are not designed to be used in tandem with TWF. Just because a character build is possible (such as a Barbarian with both Frenzy and TWF) does not mean it is viable or optimal. The fact that TWF is rendered mostly useless in some builds does not mean TWF is broken: it means that some builds should eschew TWF. Dale is very thorough with his explanation of how your house rule would effect the action economy. It would seriously change the balance of the game, and not in a uniform way for all characters.

Comment: TWF seems to be designed to grant a second attack to characters that would not normally receive additional attacks. Like a Ranger or Rogue. It's especially useful for a Rogue in that you now have two chances to trigger your Sneak Attack against particularly nasty foes that are hard to hit.

Comment: I guess TWF is really niche, then.

Comment: @DaleM Great answer, but I'm a little confused at your rogue example.  The decision of which set of actions to take is already made for you: barring some crazy circumstances, there is never a reason to make 2 dagger attacks instead of 1 dagger attack with sneak attack.  Sneak attack is the rogue's only real combat ability; you always use it if you can.  There is no real choice.  This change wouldn't change the efficacy of it, it would just add 1 dagger attack to it (at a whopping 1d4+dex).  I agree with you that this change would imbalance the game, but could you flesh this example out more?

Comment: @Percival When a Rogue with 1 attack misses, he loses his Sneak Attack too. If the Rogue has a second attack he gets another chance. When the first hit misses and the second hits the difference isn't just one hit, it's one hit + SA.

Comment: @Doval Not according to RAW.  Making an attack (hit or miss) automatically gives away your position and removes the 'hidden' attribute no matter what (page 73 of the basic rules).  Skulker feat doesn't help with melee attacks.  RAW, the rogue can only sneak-attack on their first melee attack no matter how many other attacks they get.  I suppose if they started their turn hidden next to someone they could make an attack, miss, then cunning action hide, then super-nice DM let them move away without an attack of opportunity, then sneak attack someone else, but that seems pretty rare.

Comment: @Percival It doesn't matter that the second hit doesn't get advantage; the first hit can still miss and the house rule is giving the Rogue a free second chance to deliver SA with TWF.

Comment: @Doval Only if they have an ally within 5 feet of the enemy the rogue is attacking, but in that case you wouldn't need to hide anyway and you can already make two attacks with TWF and get sneak attack on either of them.  If you're hidden (have advantage) and make your first attack, you're not hidden any more the instant the attack is made.  The instant you make a melee attack your hidden condition is gone and so is your ability to sneak attack (unless you have an ally within 5 feet of the enemy, but then you didn't need to hide in the first place and this house rule is irrelevant)

Comment: @Percival `Only if they have an ally within 5 feet of the enemy` This is probably what has you confused. Dale and I have been assuming this all along. We're not talking about fulfilling the conditions of SA, we're talking about maximizing the likelihood of hitting. With free TWF the Rogue will always do both things (Hide and TWF) to gain advantage on the first hit and have a second hit as backup if the first misses. If TWF costs a bonus action the Rogue has to choose.

Comment: @Doval actually I haven't assumed the ally but I have assumed ranged attacks with the daggers - and way the example is not the point of the answer. It is simply an illustration of one of the many ways that unintended consequences flow - there are numerous others.

Comment: @Percival - getting the SA bonus as a rogue is incredibly easy in 5e. The point is simple: Having two attacks as a rogue is beneficial in that it gives you a second opportunity to trigger a failed SA attempt. But more importantly, the finer points of how to engage in SA combat with a rogue has very little to do with the question that was asked. Personal opinions on min-maxing are fine, but comments aren't the place to hash them out. If you don't like the answer post your own.

Comment: If such edits to TWF are made so that they do not affect the monk or rogue, would TWF still be imbalanced?

Answer (score 1):

For a STR-based character in tier 1 play (or otherwise without extra attack) with no damage bonuses, feats, or fighting style, this is already slightly better than wielding a greatsword:

- Any time you finished off one opponent with your main attack, you would be able to target a different creature with your other attack.
- Two smaller attacks provide a more reliable source of damage, and reliability tends to favour the party.
- Two smaller attacks are also better for breaking a caster's focus or inflicting failed death saves.

The only real drawback would be weaker opportunity attacks, which can't be relied on to come up very often.

A bigger issue comes up with damage bonuses such as from barbarian rage or spells like Hunter's Mark, since those would now be applied twice per turn instead of only once.

It's also worth noting that the "two-weapon" fighting style provides a larger damage bonus than any other style, if you are two-weapon fighting every turn.

Once tier 2 is reached and STR-based characters gain the Extra Attack feature, it balances out a little more with greatsword builds having higher damage if not boosted in any way, but two-weapon fighting being able to achieve higher damage.

Another problem is DEX-based weapons, since DEX already offers many advantages over STR, allowing DEX characters to attack for 2d6+DEX damage as an action makes these builds much stronger.

Then there's features such as a rogue's sneak attack or a paladin's divine smite, which depend less on weapon damage and more on how often you hit - which makes two-weapon fighting more valuable.

TWF is currently niche, but not completely unused and often not terrible even when it is slightly sub-optimal. Buffing it across the board may make it "viable" in cases where it currently isn't but is likely to make it slightly OP in cases where it is currently slightly sub-optimal, and very OP in cases where it is currently viable.

Comment: I don't see how any of this is an argument for having TWF cost a bonus action. Everything you described is currently possible with unmodified TWF, and nothing is significantly improved by having TWF be free.

Comment: @sptrashcan except everything I described is *not* possible if you needed to use your bonus action for something else (like entering a barbarian rage or casting hunter's mark). TWF is mathematically better than swinging a greatsword or a rapier, but only so long as you have an available bonus action to use it. Which means the cost is the only thing that currently prevents it from being OP. Take away thay cost, and it's just straight-up better than any other option, period. Which is pretty much the definition of "over-powered".